# Create a mysql table that references foreign key and add several labels/tags of that key inside one column

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table with this fields:

```
CREATE TABLE recipes(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
image TEXT,
title TEXT,
related_product1 TEXT,
related_product2 TEXT,
related_product3 TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(related_product1) REFERENCES products(product_name),
FOREIGN KEY(related_product2) REFERENCES products(product_name),
FOREIGN KEY(related_product3) REFERENCES products(product_name)
);
```

Is there a way to create that foreign key fields in one column on just one table and add them as "labels/tags"? I don't want to limit the amount of related products.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a second table with Relations, where you save both the id's for each Table.

*(Not sure if the syntax is right like this, I normaly generate from MySQLWorkbench)*

```
CREATE TABLE recipes(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
image TEXT,
title TEXT)

CREATE TABLE relations(
recipe INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
pruduct INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(related_product) REFERENCES products(product_name),
FOREIGN KEY(related_recipe) REFERENCES recipes(id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted to know if there was a way to solve this with just one table. I guess that's not possible.

Comment: Here is some reading to that theme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form